# Cakephp2.x Jquery Ajax call to submit data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am submitting the form with jqueryajax 
my controller:

```
     class RoomDetailsController extends AppController 
        {

    var $name = "RoomDetails";

    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
    public $comonent = array('RequestHandler');



        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
        {
          $this->render('success','ajax');
        }
}
```

My index.ctp view:

```
{

       echo $this->Html->script('jquery',FALSE);   


       echo $this->js->submit('Register',array(
            'before' =>  $this->js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
            'success' => $this->js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
            'update'=> '#success'

            ));


}
```

I got an error:

```
Error: Call to a member function isAjax() on a non-object
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\atithiclient\app\Controller\RoomDetailsController.php
Line: 39
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is typo errors

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

Use `$components` instead of `$comonent`

Comment: first i am really really thank u to give me answer its work without error perfectly but sill ajax is not runnig my friend...would u plz give some idea that what i shall do to achieve the output with ajax plz give me some hint ..thanks

Comment: In fact, I don't use ajax like this. I often set $autoRender = false , and echo $result as JSON or XML 
Example
1. Controller
`function responseAjax(){
 $autoRender = false;
 echo "Here is your result"; exit;
}`
2. In JS file
`$.get('responseAjax', 
function(data){ console.log(data) // Here is your result });`